# How to upload thumnails as well as images to server with dropzone js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

The images are uploading to the server just fine. But i need thumbnail to be uploaded as well.
Can`t find that information (init options and etc) on dropzone site.
html shows src for the thumbnail like this: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA.... stores all image in string ?
How and where in dropzone i can pass it to the server (php) ?
And what should i change in upload.php ?
For now its :

```
 $ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = '../../images/gallery';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
```

Sorry for clumsy english, and thanks for responses )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnail is being stored as an SVG.

You can add a hidden input to the form that is being sent to the server and get put the thumbnail `src` information form there.

In case you can not control the form that is being transmitted to the server you can get the image `src` data with javascript and send the information in a separate request using Ajax.

However you may want to consider storing only the original image and manipulating it for your needs server side.

You can later cache these results.

Comment: I found event 'sending' "Called just before each file is sent. Gets the xhr object and the formData objects as second and third parameters, so you can modify them (for example to add a CSRF token) or add additional data."   But how to get img src ? the img tag is generated dynamicly with dropzone and has no id

Comment: Look up traversing dom in jquery or JS